# Telerik asp.net ajax grid pagination not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have made a simple cart module system

[image]

when i click the page no 2 nothing is displaying just a blank page which i am uploading it here

[image]

```
namespace PaymentGateWay
{
    public partial class Payments : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                readcoupons();
               // dt = new DataTable();
               // DataTable dtn = new DataTable();

               // dt.Columns.Add("chkstatus");
               // dt = dtn;ViewState["dt"]
                ViewState["dt"] = "NULL";

            }

 }

   private void readcoupons()
        {

            BAL.READDATA readcoupons = new READDATA();
            DataSet ds = readcoupons.ReadCoupons();
            rg_coupons.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            rg_coupons.DataBind();



        }
```

Comment: I think you have to call `readcoupons()` again after `pagingIndexChanged` method

Comment: pagingindexchanged were to call that...i am new to asp.net

Comment: Select your `telerik-grid` in aspx designer and go to its properties.. you will find `pagingIndexChanged` there probably. I haven't used `telerik-grid` yet but I am sure that it will contain method for that purpose.

Comment: i tried still not working...

Comment: protected void rg_coupons_PageIndexChanged(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            readcoupons();
           
        }

Comment: you can post it as an answer.. so that it would help other users.

Comment: nope, see my answer. The best place to provide data for the telerik AJAX grid is its NeedDataSource event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide a data source to RadGrid in its NeedDataSource event and not on initial page load only.

server code:

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    BAL.READDATA readcoupons = new READDATA();
    DataSet ds = readcoupons.ReadCoupons();
    rg_coupons.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

markup:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"></telerik:RadGrid>`enter code here`
```

Comment: You are welcome. I also edited your post title to make it relevant to the actual content and issue for anyone else with such a problem.